# Locking a file for editing by only one user at a time

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-users

I have an issue with Excel whereby when I am working on a file it is allowing other users edit the file at the same time and then when I select save I am asked if I want to overwrite the changes of the the second user.

I looked up help and it suggests unticking the "Allow changes by more than one user" on the Editing Tab within Share Workbook.  However, when I click on Share Workbook I only get an option of: "Use the old shared workbooks feature instead of the new co-authoring experience".

I would appreciate any advice in this area to resolve.

Comment: The problem you're having is "sharing" is now like the online Google sheets experience where two users can open the file simultaneously and literally watch each other make changes in real-time.  If you're using a newer version and others are using older,  I would say "use the old ...." method option makes sense.  I don't have anyway to test tho.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? This may not be possible if you're using 365.